Compute the homology groups $H_i (\mathbb R^3 - M)$ in terms of the genus of $M$.
This question is from an old publicly available qualifying exam that I’m using to learn this field (Stanford geometry and topology). I used Hatcher to learn this material a while back, but I don't recall if there was any example in his book that is like this one. Thus, all work is my own.

Have $\leftrightarrow$ denote an isomorphism, and $\underline ?$ give the interior of a space.

Let $M \subset \mathbb R^3$ be a closed, connected, 2-dimensional submanifold. Compute the homology groups $H_i (\mathbb R^3 - M)$ in terms of the genus of $M$.

Answer: For the zeroth homology groups the solution is simple: since $M$ partitions $B = \mathbb R^3 - M$ into two subspaces, it must hold that $\boxed{H_0 B \leftrightarrow \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z}$. For the higher dimensional homology groups, we'll apply the Meyer-Vietoris sequence.
Have $A$ be $M$ with some small tubular neighborhood about it, so that $A$ intersects at least slightly each connected component of $B$. By definition $A$ retracts onto $M$, so they will have equivalent homology groups. The union of the interiors $\underline A \cup \underline B$ covers the entire space $\mathbb R^3$. When we perform the intersection $A \cap B$ we "cut" the tubular neighborhood of $A$ into two pieces, each of which is retractable to a copy of $M$. Then the intersection is retractable to the disjoint union $M + M$.
For some $i \ge 1$ there is a Meyer-Vietoris sequence $$H_{i+1}\mathbb(\underline A \cup \underline B) \rightarrow H_i (A \cap B) \rightarrow H_i A \oplus H_i B \rightarrow H_i(\underline A \cup \underline B) $$
which can be rewritten as
$$H_{i+1}\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow  H_i M \oplus H_i M  \rightarrow H_i M \oplus H_i B \rightarrow H_i\mathbb R^3  $$
where all $H_i \mathbb R^3 \leftrightarrow 0$. Thus there is a contained short exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow H_i M \oplus H_i M \rightarrow H_i M \oplus H_i B \rightarrow 0$$
which implies we have an isomorphism
$$ H_i M \oplus H_i M \leftrightarrow H_i M \oplus H_i B $$
The only unique solution that satisfies this is $\boxed{H_i B \leftrightarrow H_i M}$. From this we can compute the Euler characteristic as the sum of betti numbers $$ \chi = 2 - b_1 + 1 = 3 - b_1$$
We have one boundary component, so we have the genus equation $$ 2 g = 2 - 1 - \chi = 1 - (3 - b_1) = b_1 - 2$$ thus we have the relation between the genus and homology groups given by $$ \boxed{b_1 = 2(g+1)}$$

(a) Is my relation between the genus and homology groups (via betti number) correct? I'm unsure if splitting a tubular neighborhood in half is the correct way to describe what I'm visualizing in my head, and if it's even a legal move to play.
As bonus information, I initially tried doing relative homology groups  with excision: I had a solid ball $D^3$ that surrounded $M$ and had $M$ be the excised space, but that seemed to be isomorphic to the original problem statement and got me nowhere.
If there's a good power tool or theorem that helps you solve this (faster if I got things correct), then I'd love to know.

Two comments. 1.) The identification of $A\cap B$ you are correctly visualizing does need more of a rigorous argument. You are using here that the tubular neighborhood of $M$ is trivial as a bundle over $M$, which follows from the orientability of $M$. 2.) The "The only unique solution" statements needs more justification. It's not so clear if this follows abstractly from the isomorphism; rather use what the isomorphism look like explicitly.

@Thorgott Thanks. Is the final equality between the genus and the 1st Betti number correct?

Your equality is off and I can't follow your reasoning. You simply have to relate $H_1(M)=H_1(B)$ to the genus of $M$. Also, for a flyswatter proof of this, you can look up Alexander duality (it's also in Hatcher).
